# Remove Header and style.css from Specific Post template

Tags: custom-post-types, page-attributes

I want to add some custom code so I've created a custom post file with the following content.

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Custom App
 * Template Post Type: post, page, product
 */

 ?>
 <?php get_header(); ?>
 App Code here...
```

I want to remove the header element `<header id="header" class="main-header">` and `style.css` from the custom post using function.php file.

I want to keep  `<?php get_header(); ?>` because of yoast SEO and some analytics scripts.

I don't want to hide the `main-header` using CSS `display:none` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a couple of things here...

First, you have to create a duplicate of `header.php` and we'll name it `header-custom-app.php`.  Now modify the duplicated file and remove the HTML elements you don't want.

In your template, instead of using `get_header();` you would use this:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Custom App
 * Template Post Type: post, page, product
 */

 ?>
 <?php get_header( 'custom-app' ); ?>
```

Having multiple headers, footers and sidebars is acceptable.  You can use this exact same method for both `get_footer();` and `get_sidebar();` if your template needs these or customized versions of these.

Now, for the `style.css` not being used, I can't really provide a concrete example because you haven't provided the code that shows how you currently enqueue it, so what I'm posting here operates on a few assumptions.

Assuming you're only excluding the `style.css` from this one template, you could do this:

```
if( !is_page_template( 'template-custom-app.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'yourtheme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), 'x.x' );
}
```

Obviously change the `template-custom-app.php` to whatever the name of your template is, change the `yourtheme-style` and update the `x.x` to your version number...  But what this does is it basically wraps the enqueuing of your `style.css` in a condition that says *'if NOT the custom app template, load style.css'*.

Alternatively, if your custom app has it's own CSS stylesheet that it needs you could use:

```
if( is_page_template( 'template-custom-app.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'customapp-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-app.css, array(), 'x.x' );
} else {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'yourtheme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), 'x.x' );
}
```

This last snippet assumes you have a `css` directory in your main theme directory to store secondary CSS files, if it's just in the root directory then remove the `/css` from `/css/custom-app.css`.

**Update:**

To prevent plugins from applying their scripts you'd simply need to add some dequeue instructions in the same `is_template()` condition.

```
if( is_page_template( 'template-custom-app.php' ) ) {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'plugin-style-handle' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'plugin-style-handle' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'customapp-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-app.css, array(), 'x.x' );
} else {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'yourtheme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), 'x.x' );
}
```

The tricky part here is that you need to obtain the *'handle'* from these stylesheets that are enqueued via the plugins...

You can search through the plugins looking for their enqueue functions but the easier method would be to look at the source code of your site in the `<head>` tag and locate the plugin styles you want to remove.

Here's an example:
`<link rel="stylesheet" id="searchandfilter-css" href="https://cgroupdesign.com/wp-content/plugins/search-filter/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">`

That's a stylesheet a plugin is pulling into a site.  The id is `searchandfilter-css`.

So the handle for that stylesheet would be `searchandfilter`.

If I wanted to dequeue that plugin's stylesheet I'd use this:

```
wp_dequeue_style( 'searchandfilter' );
wp_deregister_style( 'searchandfilter' );
```

You'll have to go through the source code on that template, in the head tag and in the footer and locate all the stylesheets you want to remove and discern what their handles are.

If you also want to do this with scripts you'd just use:

```
wp_dequeue_script( 'searchandfilter' );
wp_deregister_script( 'searchandfilter' );
```

Basically the same deal but change 'style' to 'script'.

Comment: It works! Also, how can I disable loading inline CSS on that custom post template. `<style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css">`

Comment: Depends what’s adding it.  

Comment: Hi, how can I remove all the CSS added by plugins except the custom-app.css

Comment: That would really depend on all of the plugins...  I'll provide an update in my answer...